# Infinite loop when trying 301 redirect with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've searched a lot, but couldn't find a solution. I'm trying to redirect php based urls with parameters to SEO friendly urls.

For example I want to redirect static.php?content_id=27 to /presentation/, but I get infinite loop error.

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^presentation/$ static.php?content_id=27
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} content_id=27
RewriteRule ^static\.php$ /presentation/? [L,R=301]
```

The old urls are indexed by google so I need this redirect.

Thanks

Comment: See the tag wiki for [tag:mod-rewrite].

Answer (score 1):

Try this  :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /static\.php\?content_id=27 [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /presentation/? [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /static.php?content_id=27 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Oh great, thank you very much. Why do I need %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f, and %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d. Thanks :

Comment: Mm not working, because if I add the same script for static.php?content_id=14 for example, it still gets content from static.php?content_id=27

Comment: You didn't understand my question at all :)